# Is it possible to install the wkhtmltopdf Python package on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert some HTML files stored locally on my computer to PDF format through a Python script, and I've tried xhtml2pdf but I ran into countless errors and decided to stop using it.

I heard that wkhtmltopdf was a better alternative and I found a Python package that integrated well into it. Unfortunately, this package requires xvfb which cannot be installed for Windows. Is there any other way to install wkhtmltopdf for Python on Windows?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's wkhtmltopdf [download list](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list), windows installer included

Answer (score 2):

- install wkhtmltopdf for Windows(http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)
- Add the bin folder to the "Path" env variable (eg: C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin)
- Install pdfkit for python bindings (pip install pdfkit)

Documentation about pdfKit can be found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit

Answer (score 0):

This is for windows & linux

- wkhtmltopdf [download list][1], for windows installer
- Add the binary "Path" to env variable

  ```
  def html_to_pdf(<html>):
     with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.html', delete=False) as temp:
         temp.write(html.encode('windows-1252'))
         temp.seek(0)
         pdfkit.from_file(temp.name, 'out.pdf') 
         temp.close()
         pdf = open('out.pdf', 'r+b')
         response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
         response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=out.pdf'
         pdf.close()
         # remove the locally created pdf file.
         os.remove(temp.name)
         return response
  ```